# Threads_cached 0 while thread_cache_size > 0

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to little bit understand with some **MySQL** (in my case - **MariaDB**) performance.

One point I found - "*threads caching*".

So - I set:

```
thread_cache_size = 4
```

in `my.cnf` and restart server.

In status I see:

```
MariaDB [mysql]> show status where variable_name like 'Threads%';
+-------------------+-------+
| Variable_name     | Value |
+-------------------+-------+
| Threads_cached    | 0     |
| Threads_connected | 2     |
| Threads_created   | 23    |
| Threads_running   | 1     |
+-------------------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Next - I run `mysqlslap`:

```
$ mysqlslap -v -u user -p --auto-generate-sql --concurrency=10 --number-of-queries=100
...
Number of clients running queries: 10
Average number of queries per client: 10
```

Thus, if I correct uderstood, after clients disconnected - server must save 4 thread in cache to use it later, but:

```
MariaDB [mysql]> show status where variable_name='Threads_cached';
+----------------+-------+
| Variable_name  | Value |
+----------------+-------+
| Threads_cached | 0     |
+----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

`Threads_cached` still have 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When a client disconnects, the client's threads are put in the cache if there are fewer than thread_cache_size threads there.

In your case, it would read

> When a client disconnects, the client's threads are put in the cache if there are fewer than 4 threads there.

Also, note the following from the [**MySQL Documentation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_thread_cache_size)

> Normally, this does not provide a notable performance improvement if you have a good thread implementation. However, if your server sees hundreds of connections per second you should normally set thread_cache_size high enough so that most new connections use cached threads.

Given this statement, 4 would seem way too low. You should set it much higher or don't set it at all (letting MariaDB set it for you).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17447/discussion-between-setevoy-and-rolandomysqldba).